# Is there any difference between dispatcher.forward() and <jsp:forward>?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Are the following operations exactly identical :

```
request.setAttribute(name,"visited");
requestDispatcher.forward(request,response)
```

and

```
<jsp:forward page="page.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="status" value="visited"/>
</jsp:forward>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both are same, only difference is separate `tag handler` class is written for `<jsp:forward>`.

See [tutorial](http://roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/TagHandlerForm.shtml) for tag handler.

Comment: For once when i first read jsp:forward tag a long time back i was confused cos as per my knowledge there was no setter for requst parameters i wonder why there is no <jsp:attr> instead of <jsp: param> to pass attributes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference. Both `<jsp:forward>` and RequestDispatcher.forward() are same in fact  `<jsp:forward>` internally used the   `RequestDispatcher.forward()`to forward the request.   is action tag and there is tag handler class .
Always remember JSP also  going convert to a servlet, by the web container.

Answer (score 0):

If only consider the forward action, there is no functional diffrerence. But they seems not fully the same.
I test the following code.

```
<%
System.out.println("source 1");
RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("1_f1.jsp");
disp.forward(request, response);
System.out.println("source 2");
%>
```

and

```
<%
System.out.println("source 1");
%>
<jsp:forward page="1_f1.jsp"/>
<%
System.out.println("source 2");
%>
```

When using `disp.forward()`, console will output "source 2".
But when using `<jsp:forward/>`, "source 2" will not be output.

The  is converted to the following statements.

```
pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
    null, true, 8192, true);
_jspx_page_context = pageContext;
if (true) {
    _jspx_page_context.forward("1_f1.jsp");
    return;
}
```

Here is a `return;` statement. So, the code after `<jsp:forward/>` will not run.